How do I fix materials on sculpts?
I am making a sculpt and I want to add a material to it. But when I do the material doesn't show up right. I have no clue what to do and can't find out what to do anywhere




Have you UV unwrapped the model? Please note that high-poly sculpts are not suitable for assigning materials to them because the UV map will be huge and performance will be bad. Better create a low-poly version of it, then UV unwrap it, and bake a Normal map. The baked Normal map can be mixed with the material's Normal map. -- The Displacement map only works in Cycles. If you want to use it add a Subdivision Surface modifier on the low-poly version model. This increases the poly count again considerably, but only at render time.
